# How to turn off conversation threading in Lotus Notes

Tags: email, lotus-notes

How do I turn off email threading (Notes calls them "conversations") in Lotus Notes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Lotus Notes 8.x client, you have to use:

File -> Application -> Properties Advanced (tab)

and then uncheck "Support Response Thread History"

Comment: That seems to be right, although it appears the administrator has disabled it :(

Answer (score 5):

In Lotus Notes client

File -> Database (mail database) -> Properties -> Advanced (tab)

un-check "Support Response Thread History"

or

In Mail Database

Click on "Show" button -> Individual Messages

Answer (score 2):

**IBM Notes 9**: Social Edition

#### Turn off conversations

Actions -> Individual Messages (Alt + A + I)

#### Turn on conversations (mail grouping)

Actions -> Conversations (Alt + A + R, R, Enter)

Answer (score 2):

This thread is quite old, but in case someone is still struggling to get rid of the thread box from the messages, here are the tasks to perform it:

- Open the message
- Select Display option in the message toolbar
- Uncheck the Thread option

Keep in mind that I'm refering to the navigation steps for **Notes 9 Basic** version.

Answer (score 1):

1. Navigate to the folder where Notes is installed
2. Locate and open **Notes.ini**
3. Locate the line *$VIEW_CONVERSATION_MODE=*
4. Set the value to **0**
5. Open Notes

Answer (score -1):

Open Any of the mail >>  Action >> clck on Show/Hide Thread