# Opened mail in IBM Lotus Notes also displays the summary and its link of all mail conversation with that subject

Tags: email, lotus-notes

When I open any mail in IBM Lotus Notes, the mail is getting opened and just above the actual mail content, all the history conversation with Sender name , date and subject is displayed. And that itself covers half of my screen as the mail conversations are too many.

If I double click on those links shown in that pane, it displays the mail content right below, hence I don't need to scroll to very down to view old mail conversation. It is like a summary of the conversations but covers half of my screen.

Since I have below 10 reputation, I'm unable to post an image.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a way to disable this funcion, In Lotus Notes

```
File -> Application -> Properties Advanced
```

and then uncheck

`Support Response Thread History`

Comment: Thanks but I have already done that. It is unchecked now and even closed and opened Lotus. Still the same.

Comment: Hey...Thanks Tom.
I found the solution,  Open any mail and click Actions-->Display--> and unselect "Thread"

Comment: Please vote up for 
http://superuser.com/questions/11028/how-to-turn-off-conversation-threading-in-lotus-notes?rq=1


-1
down vote
Open Any of the mail >> Action >> clck on Show/Hide Thread

shareedit
answered Sep 3 '14 at 18:37

Answer (score 0):

To hide this feature Aryan has the right answer, just newer version has different names. Steps:

1. open any affected email (maybe any email I didn't test that)
2. Go to Actions, Display, and uncheck - Conversation

I confirmed this on Feb 15, 2017. In the Show drop down the person may already have Individual Messages selected. Changing that or changing it back does nothing for this issue.

[image]